# Linearity of Expectation for calculating Expectation of Hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

This is from a solved problem in a probabiity textbook that I am studying.

The problem states: if $X \sim Hypergeomtric(b,r,k)$, find $E[X]$.

A familiar example is having a bag with $b$ blue marbles and $r$ red marbles. You choose at random $k$ marbles out of the box *without* replacement. If $X$ is defined as the number of blue marbles that you end up with, then it follows a hypergeometric distribution.

The solution to the problem applies Linearity of Expectation to find $E[X]$. In particular, if we define $X_i$ to be a bernouli random variable s.t.:

$X_i = \begin{cases} 1,  & \text{if the ith chosen marble is blue} \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Then, $X = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i$. And so, $E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k E[X_i]$

Now, it continues by arguing as follows: to find $P(X_i = 1)$, we note that for any particular $X_i$, all marbles are equally likely to be chosen (so far, so good). Therefore,

$P(X_i = 1) = \frac {b}{b+r}$, $\\$ for all $i \in ${$1,2,...,k$} **(1)**

From the above and using linearity of expectation it concludes that $E[X] = {k \cdot b\over b+r}$

**My point**: I can't undestand why **(1)** holds for all i. If, for example, $X_1 = 0$ (i.e. first marble we chose was red), then $P(X_2 = 1) = \frac {b}{b+r-1}$ not $\frac {b}{b+r}$, because the experiment is without replacement. Also, if $X_1 = 1$ (i.e. first marble we chose was blue),  $P(X_2 = 1) = \frac {b-1}{b+r-1}$. The same applies for the rest of the trials.

**I am missing something crucial here?**

How's the linearity of expectation being applied properly in this problem?

Comment: You are considering $P(X_2 = 1 \mid X_1 = 0),$ not $P(X_2 = 1).$

Comment: I see; but still, we would have to use conditioning, wouldn't we? I am referring to the law of total probability $P(X_2=1)=P(X_2=1 | X_1 =0) \cdot P(X_1=0) + P(X_2=1 | X_1 =1) \cdot P(X_1=1)$

Comment: I haven't done the calculations but I suspect if you do use the law of total probability, you will get that $X_2$ and $X_1$ have the same distribution, and similar for all other $X_j.$

Comment: I don't think that $\mathcal P(X_2=1) = \frac {br + b(b-1)}{(b+r)(b-1+r)}$ can be reduced to $\frac {b}{b+r}$

Comment: If you factor a $b$ you can cancel $b-1+r.$

Comment: William, you are so right, how couldn't I see that!

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

I'll just put the point across in a slightly different way to facilitate understanding.

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable that is $1$ if the $i_{th}$ marble is blue, and $0$ if not

**Blue marbles (or those of any other color ) have no preference for position**, thus if you randomly pick up the $i_{th}$ marble,

$\Bbb P(X_i) = \Bbb P(X_1) = \frac {b}{b+r}$

Now the expectation of an indicator random variable is just the probability of the event it indicates, thus $\Bbb E(X_i ) = \frac{b}{b+r},$

and  by linearity of expectation **which applies even when the variables are not independent,**

$\Bbb E(X) = \Bbb E(X_1) + \Bbb E(X_2) + ...+\Bbb E(X_k) = \frac{kb}{b+r}$

Comment: blu anil, but you don't choose the ith marble out of b + r marbles. Because you have previously picked up 1, 2, 3, ..., ith-1 marbles already. Do you see the point?

Comment: The whole point in using the expectation route is to find the *unconditional* probability *p* of picking a blue marble, and use linearity of expectation to get E[X] = np.